# Java profiling - How reliable are the values it gives?

Tags: java, text, markup

I am working on a [simple text markup Java Library](http://code.google.com/p/jtexy/) which should be, amongst other requirements, fast.

For that purpose, I did some profiling, but the results give me worse numbers that are then measured when running in non-profile mode.

So my question is - **how much reliable is the profiling?** Does that give just an informational ratio of the time spent in methods? Does that take JIT compiler into account, or is the profiling mode only interpreted? I use NetBeans Profiler and Sun JDK 1.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running profiling, you'll always incur a performance penalty as something has to measure the start/stop time of the methods, keep track of the objects of the heap (for memory profiling), so there is a management overhead.

However, it will give you clear pointers to find out where bottlenecks are. I tend to look for the methods where the most cumulative time is spent and check whether optimisations can be made. It is also useful to determine whether methods are called unnecessarily.

With methods that are very small, take the profile results with a pinch of salt, sometimes the process of measuring can take more time than the method call itself and skew the results (it might appear that a small, often-called method has more of a performance impact).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Because of instrumentation profiled code on average will run slower than non-profiled code. Measuring speed is not the purpose of profiling however.

The profiling output will point you to bottlenecks, places that threads spend more time in,  code that behaves worse than expected, or possible memory leaks.

You can use those hints to improve said methods and profile again until you are happy with the results.

A profiler will not be a solution to a coding style that is x% slower than optimal however, you still need to spend time fine-tuning those parts of your code that are used more often than others.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised by the fact that you get worst results when profiling your application as instrumenting java code will typically always slow its execution. This is  actually nicely captured by the Wikipedia page on [Profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) which mentions that instrumentation *can causes changes in the performance of  a program, potentially causing inaccurate inaccurate results and [heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)* (due to [the observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29): *observers affect what they are observing, by the mere act of observing it alone*).

Having that said, if you want to measure speed, I think that you're not using the right tool. Profilers are used to find bottlenecks in an application (and for that, you don't really care of the overall impact). But if you want to benchmark your library, you should use a performance testing tool (for example, something like [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)) that will be able to give you an average execution time per call. You will get much better and more reliable results with the right tool.

Answer (score 2):

The Profiling should have no influence on the JIT compiler. The code inserted to profile your application however will slow the methods down quite a bit.
Profillers work on severall different models, either they insert code to see how long and how often methods are running or they only take samples by repeatedly polling what code is currently executed.
The first will slow down your code quite a bit, while the second is not 100% accurate, as it may miss some method calls.

Answer (score 1):

Profiled code is bound to run slower as mentioned in most of the previous comments. I would say, use profiling to measure only the relative performance of various parts of your code (say methods). Do not use the measures from a profiler as an indicator of how the code would perform overall (unless you want a worst-case measure, in which case what you have would be an overestimated value.)

Answer (score 1):

I have found I get different result depending on which profiler I use.  However the results are often valid, but a different perspective on the problem.  Something I often do when profiling CPU usage is to enable memory allocation profiling.  This often gives me different CPU results (due to the increased overhead caused by the memory profiling) and can give me some useful places to optimise.